# A colour TV is hired for €$100$ in the first year and in each subsequent year the charge is four-fifths of the previous year.

Tags: sequences-and-series

A colour TV is hired for €$100$ in the first year and in each subsequent year the charge is four-fifths of the previous year. What is the total charge paid over 5 years by the hirer?

$$(100)(0.8)^{n−1}
=(100)(0.8)^{5−1}
=(100)(0.8)^4
=(100)(0.32768)
=32.768$$

could anyone tell me its right or wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your computation. Are you saying the total is $33$?

Comment: Think about it: Your answer is that the total charge is $33$ euros. But during the first year already, it's $100$ euros. Can this be correct?

Comment: You have calculated the charge paid in the fifth year. The question asks for the total charge paid over the five years.

Comment: In this case, when there are only five years. It's not too bad to calculate each year separately.
First year, the charge is $100$ euros. Second, year, it's $100\times 0.8=80$ euros. Third year, it's $100\times 0.8^2$ euros ... etc.

Comment: Surely one should just buy a cheap laptop or tablet for, say, 80 pounds. :)

Comment: Although you can calculate by adding up the prices year by year, I suspect this question is specifically designed to test you on the finite geometric series formula. Without more context, it is impossible to know however.

Comment: @ArjmandMasood Please edit your question to include where the question comes from. What course are you studying? If you do this your question can be reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the sum of a finite geometric series:

$$S_n = \frac{a_1 (1-r^n)}{1-r}$$

where $a_1$ is the first term, $r$ is the common ratio, $n$ is the number of terms, and $S_n$ is the sum at the $n$th term.

Can you proceed now?

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong.

First year = \$100 * 80% = \$80

Second year = (\$100 * 80% ) * 80% = \$80 * 80% = 64$  [first year's amount times 80%]

Third year = ...

As Toby Mak points out, the sum of a finite geometric series would do.